# How to get the last field in a Mysql database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have mysql database and I want to get the last ID from field in a table .

example : -

```
id   Value
1    david
2    jone
3    chris
```

I want a function return 3 if this table exist .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to select the ID of the most recently inserted row in a table with an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you will likey be interested in MySQL's [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT id
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use the following code ::

```
 $lastId = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The question was to get the last id, not the whole row. And why do you repost a 3 year old answer?