# How to get the last ID with mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a form with two stages, the first is to put the information but the second is the UPDATE to add the photo. So what I want to do is retrieve the last auto incremented ID to update the data, I used `LAST_INSERT_ID ()`

but I realize it is the update everywhere. Do you have a suggestion for me to help me? Thank you and sorry sorry for my english.

You can see here what I did:

```
 $sql = 'UPDATE 'jj_news' SET 
cover_picture="'.$large_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'].'",
 min_picture="'.$thumb_image_name.$_SESSION['user_file_ext'].'", statut="1",
 edited="'.date('Y-m-d h:i:s').'" WHERE id_news= LAST_INSERT_ID(id_news)';
       mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570521/how-to-get-the-last-field-in-a-mysql-database-with-php?rq=1

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You can get the id using $id = mysql_insert_id(); after inserting

Comment: "but I realize it is the update everywhere"... means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloody hell, why don't you just store the damn id, into a hidden post field and pass it to the second page on form submit?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get your id in the "second stage". You have to get it immediately after running insert.

So, get it in the first stage, store it in a session and then use in the second one.

Comment: Can i have an idea please ?

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `xy` (`xy`) VALUES ('$_POST[xy]');");
    $insertId = mysql_insert_id();
    mysql_query("UPDATE xy SET xy='$xy' WHERE id='$insertId'");
```

only know from the mysql_* function...

**use mysqli or PDO**, but if this helps you i´m glad.....

Comment: *"I have a form with two stages"* --- this will not work in the OP's case. The INSERT and the UPDATE queries are in two different pages.

Comment: @Juhana oh you are right...overread it...then his query was totally wrong...i thought he meant this...with the last inserted row it wont work becaus: What happens if someone else submitted form one while you are in part two?

Comment: Thank you but it's must be necessaryin the same form for all ? I want to say

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following function.

```
function getLastId($tablename,$id_field){
$id=0;
$sql="select ".$id_field." from ".$tablename." order by ".$id_field." desc limit 1" ;
$res_obj=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error);
if(mysql_num_rows($res_obj)>0){
$result=mysql_fetch_array($res_obj); //we have only on row and column.
$id=$result[$id_field]; //set the last greator Id value;
}
return $id;
}
$newid=getLastId("yourtable","id_field")+1;
//insert your data using $newid instead of autocomplete.
//use $newid during update if update is on new page make a session of $newid. like
$_SESSION['update_id']=$newid;
```

this function make manual increment of id column, instead of auto increment. I think it is ease to control your situation using this function.

Comment: Please read something on "race condition" and why it is important. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Raphael, i think it's the best idea. Thanks you so munch, i'm go to try and i will tell you if everythings are oK.